# @Autowire SqlSessionFactoryBean in @Service is giving null

Tags: spring, mybatis, autowired

I am desperately trying to @Autowire mybatis SqlSessionFactoryBean in one of my annotated Service class. As expected, No bean definition for service class is present in ApplicationContext.xml because it is annotated whereas  SqlSessionFactoryBean bean definition is presented.

```
@Service(value = "MyService")
public class MyService
{
    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean;

    // extra code
}
```

Both 'MyService' and 'SqlSessionFactoryBean' classed are instantiating by spring but null is being set against sqlSessionFactoryBean variable in service class.

Comment: Did you enable annotation processing? `<context:annotation-config/>` in your application context? What does the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` write to the log? Is he actually processing your bean `MyService`?

Comment: @Talal please post your Spring config.

Comment: I am successful in catching breakpoint at Autowired field , doesn't it mean that MyService is being instantiated by spring. I am not instantiating MyService anywhere in the code. By the way, sqlSessionFactoryBean is instantiated in PostConstruct method of Myservice, although I was expecting sqlSessionFactoryBean to be initialized right after Autowired declaration